# flutter google maps corrupts after return from a screen containing input

Tags: android, flutter, google-maps-flutter

I do develop an application which uses google maps on it's home page. As of andoird 12 I have discovered that google maps shows white page or some kind of partially rendrered  map, after return from a screen which loads android keyboard. The key point is that all things working well, until the next screen shows android keyboard. After you focus to the input TextField, return to map, you have corrupted map. If you have'nt got corruption first time, you should see some flickering at the bottom, repeat again after 2-4 times you will see white map. Please help me to overcome this issue. Here is the code illustrating the problem
[github repo](https://github.com/Aidamir/flutter_gmap_corruption) just put your google API_KEY in manifest.xml and run. Thanks.

main.dart:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:mytest/input_page.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  CameraPosition initialCameraPosition = const CameraPosition(target: LatLng(40.7384685, -73.9890675), zoom: 0.0);
  void _moveToInputPage() {
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const InputPage())
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: const Center(
          child: GoogleMap(
        initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(target: LatLng(40.7384685, -73.9890675), zoom: 0.0)
      )),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _moveToInputPage,
        child: const Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

input_page.dart:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class InputPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const InputPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _InputPageState createState() => _InputPageState();
}

class _InputPageState extends State<InputPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();
      },
      child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text("Input Page"),
          ),
          body: Center(
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.grey[300],
              child: const TextField(
//   Enable autofocus to see corrupted map every time.
//              autofocus: true,
              ),
            ),
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This setting does the magic https://pub.dev/documentation/google_maps_flutter/latest/google_maps_flutter/AndroidGoogleMapsFlutter/useAndroidViewSurface.html

```dart
import 'package:device_info/device_info.dart';

void main() async {
  if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.android) {
    DeviceInfoPlugin deviceInfo = DeviceInfoPlugin();
    var androidInfo = await deviceInfo.androidInfo;
    if (androidInfo.version.sdkInt > 28) {
      AndroidGoogleMapsFlutter.useAndroidViewSurface = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: When I open a new page on top of the map, the map shortly blinks through the newly opened page. With this unwanted behaviour I cannot set useAndroidViewSurface. Other suggestions? Anybody?

Comment: I have same kind of blinking problem but it happens on certain devices works good on android 10 or above. I am having issues with android 7